# React SSR with async reducer - Unexpected key found in preloadedState argument passed to createStore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to implement code splitting in my redux code of react application using the `injectReducer` approach. It works well with only client side rendering but fails with server side rendering when I try to dump the server sent store into redux as it happens at root level of my client code before I reach the page level component that calls the inject reducer.

For instance `'pageASate'` is added dynamically into redux using inject reducer. On server I add it dynamically and render the page. Once the page renders on client and the store dump `{ 'pageAState': '...some data'}` is recein=ved from server, I try to initialise redux with same at root level.

> const store = configureStore(window.**SERVER_STATE**)

Since the server state has the 'pageAState' which is not part of reducers list sent to redux, it throws below error:

> Unexpected key "pageASate" found in preloadedState argument passed to
> createStore. Unexpected keys will be ignored.

Hence the store is getting initialised without state of pageA sent by server causing he page to get blank and re-render again once data is fetched again on client. How can it be handled?